# Does bitbucket implement a temporary lockout for too many failed login attempts through a git push?

Tags: git, bitbucket

And, if they do, how long does the lockout last?

Comment: Might be best to directly ask BitBucket that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that I can see.

The "locked out" topic comes up with FishEye and Crucible (see "[Users are locked out of FishEye and Crucible REST APIs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AOD/Users+are+locked+out+of+FishEye+and+Crucible+REST+APIs)"),
... but not when administrating a bitbucket repository (see "[Granting Users Access to a Repository](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Granting+Users+Access+to+a+Repository)")

All the logon errors reported through the bitbucket API didn't seem to have locked out any user (see "[sourcetree hosted projects - Bitbucket API call failed](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/25681/sourcetree-hosted-projects-bitbucket-api-call-failed)").